# Subsetting into multiple dataframes and adding a new column to each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

There are certain problems I am facing while manipulating the data below :-

```
df:

|index |
------ 
  1   
  2
  3 
  4

df_A :
 
 |index| price|
 --------------
    1  |  20
    2  |  0

df_B :
  |index| price|
 --------------
    2  |  20
    3  |  0

df_C :
  |index| price|
 --------------
    3  |  20
    4  |  0
```

1> I am trying to subset the dataframe into multiple dataframes of size 2 as mentioned above
and create an extra column in each dataframe whose values will be 20 except the last row that
would be 0

I have tried to write the code but getting some error as well as a different result as follows

My Code -

```
n = 2
list_of_df = []
for i in range(0, (df.index[-1]-2)+2):
df_i = df.loc[i:i+n, :]
for j in df_i['index']:
    if j == df_i['index'].iloc[-1]:
        df_i['price'] = 20
    else:
        df_i['price'] = 0
list_of_df.append(df_i)
```

Ouput :-

```
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
<input>:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

But that still leads to the result where my subset dataframes looks like this

```
  df_A :
 
 |index| price|
 --------------
    1  |  20
    2  |  20
```

How should I modify my code to resolve such issues ?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you really have a `df` with index column with values `1-5` and no other columns? And why is there no `df_D` with index 4 5?

Comment: Sorry I need to eliminate 5, this is a dummy table @Henry Ecker